# Find The range of the function

Tags: calculus

Find the range of the function $f(x)=\frac{1}{x+2 \cos x}$.

I tried like this $-2<2 \cos x<2$ then $\frac{1}{x-2}<\frac{1}{x+2\cos x}<\frac{1}{x+2}$ and then can't find the range of $\frac{1}{x-2}$ and $\frac{1}{x+2}$.

Comment: Hint: Find the range of $x+2\cos x$ first.  Then see what values the reciprocal can take.  Also try formatting, see what has been done by clicking the edit button.

Answer (score 2):

The function $x+2\cos x$ can take on any real value. So you essentially need to find the range of the function $${1\over y}$$ where $y$ can be anything - the answer is therefore $\mathbb{R}-\{0\}$.

Comment: but the exp can take x=0

Answer (score 0):

Continuing NotNotLogical's answer, do not forget that $x+2\cos x=0$ has one solution; it cannot be expressed in terms of elemental functions and only numerical methods will find the solution. It is quite close to $x=-\frac {\pi}{3}$.